# Final project ideas - computational geometry

Tags: soft-question, computational-geometry

Next semester I am teaching (the programming part) of a course in **Computational Geometry**. There are 14 weeks of class, two "pure theoretical/blackboard" hours per week, one "theoretical/blackboard exercises" hour per week and one "computer lab" hour per week.

My intention for the "computer lab" sessions is that the students work (almost from day one) on a **programming project** that they can submit at the end of the course. My thoughts for the structure and evaluation of the projects are more or less the same than in [this link](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Etaoju/cse546/finalprojects.htm). To sum up: students can either design a graphical applet that illustrates some algorithm, work on an open problem or develop an application of Computational Geometry to other areas.

However, I am not an expert in Computational Geometry and I **would like you to give me some suggestions of interesting topics for the final projects**.

Let me give some context for the level of the projects:

- The students are 4th-year (that's **last year** in Spain) **undergraduates in Mathematics**. Their programming background is a two-semester course on basic programming in Python and two one-semester courses on Numerical Analysis where they did some programming in Matlab. Some of them have a wider background and a small fraction of them are also last-year Computer Science undergraduates.
- The **textbook** we are going to follow is: [A Short Course in Computational Geometry and Topology](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319059563) by H. Edelsbrunner. (The theory professor chose it).

In previous years this course has been Machine-Learning-oriented, so I might also suggests some projects related with ML.